# Auto filter when paste data into richtextbox vb.net

Tags: regex, vb.net

ex i paste

```
Phone: 111-111-111
Phone: 222-222-222
Phone: 333-333-333
```

i want richtextbox auto filter and show in the richtextbox format

```
111-111-111
222-222-222
333-333-333
```

but my code will show at the richtexbox

```
Phone: 111-111-111
Phone: 222-222-222
Phone: 333-333-333111-111-111
222-222-222
333-333-333
```

i want remove paste data and show data filter

```
Private Sub RichTextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RichTextBox1.TextChanged
    For Each m As Match In Regex.Matches(RichTextBox1.Text, getnumber)
        RichTextBox1.Text &= m.Value & Environment.NewLine
    Next
End Sub

Dim getnumber As String = "(?:\d{3}\-){2}\d{3}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you concatenate your RichTextBox's text with the filtered text *after* the text has been changed. In your example, the following text:

```
Phone: 111-111-111
Phone: 222-222-222
Phone: 333-333-333
```

Is added to your RichTextoBox and afterwards, you add the following text:

```
111-111-111
222-222-222
333-333-333
```

Since you only add a NewLine after each match (e.g `111-111-111`), the two strings above will be shown without a NewLine separating them.

To solve this problem, add a temporary string variable that will contain the "filtered text", as you call it, and at the end set this variable's value to your RichTextBox's text:

```vb
Private getnumber As String = "(?:\d{3}\-){2}\d{3}"

Private Sub RichTextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles RichTextBox1.TextChanged
    Dim filteredText As String = ""
    For Each m As Match In Regex.Matches(RichTextBox1.Text, getnumber)
        filteredText &= m.Value & Environment.NewLine
    Next
    ' TrimEnd() will remove the last NewLine
    Me.RichTextBox1.Text = filteredText.TrimEnd()
End Sub
```